# Como haria para que los checkbox se seleccione uno por uno

Tags: flutter, dart

Muy buenas tardes, necesito ayuda en un problema que tengo en flutter.
Seria en los checkboxs que no se selecciona cuando le doy click a cada uno
Lo que pasa es que al dar click a un checkbox hace como que la pantalla se recarga y el checkbox no se marque
Yo quisiera que al dar click a uno se marque solo ese y asi sucesivamente con los demas.
Gracias de antemano ojala puedan ayudarme

**Este seria el api**

```
Future<List<UiOption>?> uiOptionGetByApplicationId(GetByIdRequest request) async {
    final mapResponse = await dialer(
        Uri.http(
            _urlAuthorization, "api/authorization/UiOptionGetByApplicationId"),
        request.toJson());

    var result = UiOptionGetByApplicationIdResponse.fromJson(mapResponse);

    return result.data;
}
```

**ESTA ES LA CLASE "UIOPTION"**

```
class UiOption {
  int? id;
  int? applicationId;
  String? code;
  String? description;
  String? type;
  String? classs;
  String? url;
  int? state;
  String? action;
  bool? done;

  UiOption({
    this.id,
    this.applicationId,
    this.code,
    this.description,
    this.type,
    this.classs,
    this.url,
    this.state,
    this.action,
  }) : done = false;
}
```

**ESTE EL CODIGO PARA LA PANTALLA DE LOS CHECKBOXS**

Aqui va el propiedad Checkbox y creo que es donde esta el error pero no logro encontrarlo

```
class _UiOptionRolPageState extends State<UiOptionRolPage> {
  Future<List<UiOption>?> uiOptionGetByApplicationId() async {
    var applicationid = widget.idAppli;
    var meta = new MetaRequest(
        modifier: "FLUTTER",
        currentPage: 0,
        size: 0,
        identifier: Uuid().v1().toString());

    var request = new GetByIdRequest(id: applicationid, meta: meta);

    return await SecurityProvider().uiOptionGetByApplicationId(request);
  }

  @override
  String _nombre = '';
  bool? _checked = false;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
        title: (Text('Rol/Aplicativo/UI')),
        actions: <Widget>[
          BackButton(),
          IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.check),
            onPressed: () => print('Boton 3 puntos'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<UiOption>?>(
            future: uiOptionGetByApplicationId(),
            builder: (context, data) {
              if (data.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting &&
                  data.hasData) {
                var userList = data.data;
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: userList!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        //key: Key("$index"),
                        trailing: Checkbox(
                          value: userList[index].done,
                          onChanged: (checked) {
                            setState(() {
                              userList[index].done = checked;
                            });
                          },
                          activeColor: PrimaryColor,
                        ),
                        title: Text(userList[index].description ?? ""),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          child: Text(
                              userList[index].description!.substring(0, 1)),
                          backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: MainDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**IMAGEN DE LA PANTALLA**
[image: Esto seria el resultado pero como les dije al momento de darle click a un checkbox no se selecciona y hace que se cargue la pantalla de nuevo]

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el problema se pueda dar por varios motivos.

El primero es que estás la llamando la función `uiOptionGetByApplicationId()` cada vez que se construye la página o Widget, con el cual la información que tenias guardada en `var userList` se reescribe.

La segunda seguramente sea que estés reescribiendo la variable `var userList` cada vez que llamas al `setState`.

Te dejo comentados los cambios y consejos en el código que creo que te ayudarán:

```
class _UiOptionRolPageState extends State<UiOptionRolPage> {

      Future<List<UiOption>?> uiOptionGetByApplicationId() async {
        //Esto dejar como está
      }

      //Crea esta variable para tratar la información del Future
      Future<List<UiOption>? _listUIOptionFuture;
      //Crea esta otra variable, para tratar de forma persistente la información que tienes en el dispositivo
      List<UiOption>? _listUIOPtion;

      //Emplea el initState para cargar la información una sola vez al iniciar la página
      @override
      void initState() {
        
        _listUIOptionFuture = uiOptionGetByApplicationId(); 
        //Esto es lo que tendrás que llamar cada vez que quieras obtener otra vez la información des de la API, aunque si no le envias la nueva información, te devolerá la checklist como estaba
        // No hace falta llamar setState para ver la nueva información. El Futurebuilder ya se encarga de ello.

        super.initState();
      }

    @override
      String _nombre = "";
      bool? _checked = false;
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: FutureBuilder<List<UiOption>?>(
                future: _listUIOptionFuture, //Usa la nueva variable como Future
                builder: (context, data) {
              if (data.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting && data.hasData) {
                
                //Condicional para assignar una sola vez, 
                if(_listUIOPtion == null) _listUIOPtion = data.data;
                //Tendrás que usar otra variable para saber cuando quieres actualizar esta información forzadamente
                
                if(_listUIOPtion != null){//Condicional para comprobar que la lista no esta vacia
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _listUIOPtion!.length, //Modifica la variables pertinentes
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        trailing: Checkbox(
                          value: _listUIOPtion[index].done,
                          onChanged: (checked) {
                            setState(() {
                              _listUIOPtion[index].done = checked;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    });
                }
                else return Center(child: Text("Sin lista"),);
                
              } else {
                //Esta línea no tendría que ser necesaria, pero te puede llegar a suceder que el Future carge antes de que se construya el Widget y entonces solo te saldría la rosquilla de cargando, eternamente. 
                _listUIOptionFuture = uiOptionGetByApplicationId(); 
                return Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```